# Unable to compile class for JSP: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a problem with JSP (I am using Tomcat), I would like to set the title in the browser window to a string in my Config class, which you can see below, the problem is that I get an error. I already have searched this problem at the internet but nothing works for me.

Index file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="test.*" %>
<%
  Config cfg = new Config();
%>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= cfg.getSiteTitle() %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  $END$
  </body>
</html>
```

Config class:
    package test;

```
public class Config {
    private String siteTitle = "Test";

    public String getSiteTitle() {
        return siteTitle;
    }

    public void setSiteTitle(String siteTitle) {
        this.siteTitle = siteTitle;
    }
}
```

Tomcat error log:

```
15-May-2016 12:35:52.483 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 4 in the jsp file: /CMS/web/index.jsp
Config cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
2: <%@ page import="test.*" %>
3: <%
4:   Config cfg = new Config();
5: %>
6: <html>
7:   <head>


An error occurred at line: 4 in the jsp file: /CMS/web/index.jsp
Config cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
2: <%@ page import="test.*" %>
3: <%
4:   Config cfg = new Config();
5: %>
6: <html>
7:   <head>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 4 in the jsp file: /CMS/web/index.jsp
Config cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
2: <%@ page import="test.*" %>
3: <%
4:   Config cfg = new Config();
5: %>
6: <html>
7:   <head>


An error occurred at line: 4 in the jsp file: /CMS/web/index.jsp
Config cannot be resolved to a type
1: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
2: <%@ page import="test.*" %>
3: <%
4:   Config cfg = new Config();
5: %>
6: <html>
7:   <head>


Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java    :61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I hope I have give you enough information, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Your **Config** class cannot be resolved to a Type. It means that **Config** class is either not in your runtime classpath or it is not imported in your jsp.

I noticed that you imported test.*
If **Config** class is not directly under package test, it won't be recognized by jsp.

Explicitly import your **Config** Class at the same place where you import test.* should solve your problem, like so:
`<%@ page import="test.whatever.Config" %>`

#### Suggestions

Please, please, please do not include java code in your jsp. Use jsp for the **view** with EL, servlet as controller. You will Create the Config instance in a Servlet and then save the instance in a request/session scope, then you can access your config in jsp preferably using EL. Search "MVC jsp servlet" will give you tons of information on exactly how to do it.